# How to create Hangouts chat message via API with a link to Video meeting

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I'm trying to create Google Hangouts Chat message with a link to new Video meeting.

So far I managed to send a regular message, but I cannot find how to create a video meeting and send a link there:

```golang
msg := chat.Message {
    Text: "test msg",
}

_, err := chatService.Spaces.Messages.Create(spaceID, &msg).Do()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

In the chat itself it's easily doable:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- Include the link [in a simple message](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic#including_links_in_message_text):

> If you include a plain link URL in your message text, such as http://example.com/foo, Hangouts Chat uses this as the link text and automatically hyperlinks that text to the specified URL.

If you don't want the link URL to show up, you can provide an alternate link text for this link, using the following syntax:

```
<video-meeting-url|your link text>
```

- You can also customize your message to a higher degree by sending a [card message](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards). You can for example, provide a custom image for the meeting link, [as explained here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards#image_widget).

#### UPDATE:

Before doing this, you have to create a video meeting and get its link. **You cannot create a video meeting with Hangouts Chat API**.

As you can see in the official documentation, Chat API can only be used to manage [spaces](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces) (that is, chat rooms and direct messages), as well as its [members](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.members) and [messages](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages). Video meetings are not part of Hangouts Chat but of Hangouts Meet, and there is no open Hangouts Meet API.

#### Reference:

- [Including links in message text](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic#including_links_in_message_text)
- [Card Messages: Image widget](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards#image_widget)

Comment: Thank you, @lamblichus! However, I don't have the link. I'd like to create a new hangout meeting and link to this one. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: @JanPetr Sorry I didn't understand your question before. I updated my answer accordingly, and no, you cannot programmatically create a video meeting with Hangouts Chat API.